# it is possible get email list using imapX?

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, imapx

I downloaded the [ImapX](http://www.hellowebapps.com/products/imapx/) library and I need know it is possible get email list using imapx? if not, what is the best quick and fast way to do it? the google API looks like a bit confusing. and I need it to winforms application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample provided on the ImapX site is pretty clear :

```
var client = new ImapX.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
client.Connection();
client.LogIn(userName, userPassword);
var messages = client.Folders["INBOX"].Search("ALL", true);
```

So, the answer to your question is: Yes!

I haven't used ImapX, so I cannot confirm that this code is working. Personnaly, I prefer [MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) which seems to be more complete (it's not limited to IMAP) but lacks documentation.

Comment: Suggestions for working together with: 
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail https://higlabo.codeplex.com/documentation 
https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/ 
https://imapx.codeplex.com/